# Finding if $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+2)}{x^2} \, dx $ converges, with two conficting solutions?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Consider the problem where the following integral converges or not:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+2)}{x^2} \,dx $$

I tried to solve it in two different ways but the results conflict. I am not sure why.

---

**First Solution:**

Using comparison criterion we can prove that it converges because

$$ \frac {\sin(x+2)}{x^2} \leq \frac {1}{x^2} $$

and  $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx < + \infty$$ converges as a p-intergral with $p=2 > 1$

---

**Second Solution** 
$$ \frac {\sin(x+2)}{x^2} \leq \frac {x+2}{x^2} = \frac {1}{x} + \frac {2}{x^2} $$

Where this converges 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2} dx$$
but this diverges
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx$$

Thus the initial integral also diverges *because one part of its sum diverges*

---

> The solutions conflict and I know that something is wrong with the
>   second solution. But I cannot spot what went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: They do not conflict, the upper bound in your second solution is not sharp enough to be an integrable function.

Comment: @nicomezi What do you mean "sharp enough" ?

Comment: I could say that $0 \le \frac 1 x$, and, as you said, $\frac 1 x$ is not integrable. Yet this does not imply that the zero function is not integrable. (and this is basically the reasonning you have done in the second solution).

Comment: True, thank you!

Comment: It is not proper  to keep editing the question long after answers appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is integrabilty near $0$. Since $\frac {\sin x} x \to 1$ and $ \int_0^{1} \frac  1 x dx$ does not converge, the given integral does not converge.

It is also not true that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {x^{2}} d x<\infty$.

Answer for the edited version: The integral is convergent because $-\frac 1 {x^{2}} \leq \frac {\sin x} {x^{2}} \leq \frac 1 {x^{2}}$.

[I do not understand why you are considering $\sin (x+2)$].

(The question was edited again after  I posted this answer).

Comment: What if the edges of the intergral where $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x^2} dx $$ ? I edited my question @Kavi

Comment: I have edited my answer too!

Comment: I did a typo again, I am sorry. The initial integral meant to be with x + 2 $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x+2)}{x^2} dx $$ @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @nicomezi fixed that, thank you

Comment: This doesn't say why the second solution is wrong, does it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP edied the question twice. There  was no $\sin (x+2)$ in the question before.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: did he add the second solution after the fact ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As you can see from one of his comments the question was only about convergence of the integral of $\frac {\sin x} {x^{2}}$. So I mentioned that I don't know why he even considered $sin (x+2)$ in the second solution. You can see that he still doesn't have $\sin (x+2)$ in the title.

Comment: @Kavi, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I'll accept your answer since you answered first and you've helped me in other questions too, alright?

Answer (score 5):

You are writing

$$\int f(x)dx\le \int g(x)dx$$

and conclude that if $$ \int g(x)dx$$ diverges, so does $$\int f(x)dx.$$

This is wrong.